# Bokeh: How to show both color and marker type in legend

Tags: bokeh

I want to plot legend that shows both line color and marker type when using boekh package in jupyter notebook.

I have many lines in one plot. To distinguish them, I tried my best to distinguish them by evenly distributing their color in the color space. However, when the number of lines reaches e.g. 9, the color of some lines are quite similar. So, I want to add different marker types on top of different colors so that when two lines are similar in color, they have different marker type. 
It was straight-forward with matplotlib, but not straight-forward with bokeh. Below is the code I have now that can only plot legend with color.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, ColumnDataSource, save,     output_notebook, output_file, reset_output
from bokeh.io import export_svgs,export_png
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, Legend
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
import colorsys # needed for generating N equally extinguishable colors
from operator import add # needed for add lists

d = {'Sex': ['male', 'male','male','male', 'male','male','female','female','female','female','female','female'], 'age': [20, 20,20, 25,25,25,20, 20,20,25,25,25], 'working_hours': [20,30,40,20,30,40,20,30,40,20,30,40],'income': [1000, 2000,3000,1500, 2500,3500,1100, 2100,3100,1300, 2300,3300] }
values = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

x_var = 'working_hours'
x_var_dimension = 'H'
y_var = 'income'
y_var_dimension = 'Dollars'
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[("data (x,y)", "(@x, @y)")])
TOOLS=[hover]
p= figure(width=1200, height=600,tools=TOOLS, x_axis_type='linear', x_axis_label='%s [%s]'%(x_var, x_var_dimension),y_axis_label='%s [%s]'%(y_var, y_var_dimension))
nr_expressions_row_col=9
figs_array_row_col = []
figs_row_row_col=[]
legend_its_row_col = []
legend_its_row_col_renderer = []
loop_count = 0;
for key, group in values.groupby(['Sex']):
    for key_sub1, group_sub1 in group.groupby(['age']):
        loop_count+=1
        #print type(key)
        #print group_sub1
        #print count
        #hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[("data (x,y)", "($x, $y)")])
        x_data = group_sub1[x_var].values;
        y_data =  group_sub1[y_var].values
        (color_r,color_g,color_b) = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(loop_count*1.0/nr_expressions_row_col, 1, 1)
        plot_row_col_line = p.line(x_data, y_data,line_color=(int(255*color_r),int(255*color_g),int(255*color_b)))
        legend_its_row_col.append(("%s %s"%(key,key_sub1), [plot_row_col_line]))


legend_row_col = Legend(items = legend_its_row_col, location=(0,0))
legend_row_col.click_policy = 'hide'
legend_row_col.background_fill_alpha = 0
p.add_layout(legend_row_col, 'left')

figs_row_row_col.append(p)
figs_array_row_col.append(figs_row_row_col)

grid_row_col = gridplot(figs_array_row_col)
reset_output()
output_notebook()
show(grid_row_col)
```

What I can get with my code is:
[image: actual results]
What I want is:
[image: expected results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give the result you want, I've added a cyclic list with all the markers that can be used with `p.scatter` and it takes another marker every iteration. After this I add it with the line glyph to the legend dictionary.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, ColumnDataSource, save, output_file, reset_output
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, Legend
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
import colorsys # needed for generating N equally extinguishable colors
from itertools import cycle

d = {'Sex': ['male', 'male','male','male', 'male','male','female','female','female','female','female','female'], 'age': [20, 20,20, 25,25,25,20, 20,20,25,25,25], 'working_hours': [20,30,40,20,30,40,20,30,40,20,30,40],'income': [1000, 2000,3000,1500, 2500,3500,1100, 2100,3100,1300, 2300,3300] }
values = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

x_var = 'working_hours'
x_var_dimension = 'H'
y_var = 'income'
y_var_dimension = 'Dollars'
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[("data (x,y)", "(@x, @y)")])
TOOLS=[hover]
p= figure(width=1200, height=600,tools=TOOLS, x_axis_type='linear', x_axis_label='%s [%s]'%(x_var, x_var_dimension),y_axis_label='%s [%s]'%(y_var, y_var_dimension))
nr_expressions_row_col=9
figs_array_row_col = []
figs_row_row_col=[]
legend_its_row_col = []
legend_its_row_col_renderer = []
loop_count = 0;
markers = ['circle', 'square', 'triangle', 'asterisk', 'circle_x', 'square_x', 'inverted_triangle', 'x', 'circle_cross', 'square_cross', 'diamond', 'cross']
pool = cycle(markers)
for key, group in values.groupby(['Sex']):
    for key_sub1, group_sub1 in group.groupby(['age']):
        loop_count+=1
        x_data = group_sub1[x_var].values;
        y_data =  group_sub1[y_var].values
        (color_r,color_g,color_b) = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(loop_count*1.0/nr_expressions_row_col, 1, 1)
        plot_row_col_line = p.line(x_data, y_data,line_color=(int(255*color_r),int(255*color_g),int(255*color_b)))
        plot_row_col_glyph = p.scatter(x_data, y_data, color=(int(255*color_r),int(255*color_g),int(255*color_b)), size=10, marker=next(pool))
        legend_its_row_col.append(("%s %s"%(key,key_sub1), [plot_row_col_line, plot_row_col_glyph]))


legend_row_col = Legend(items = legend_its_row_col, location=(0,0))
legend_row_col.click_policy = 'hide'
legend_row_col.background_fill_alpha = 0
p.add_layout(legend_row_col, 'left')

figs_row_row_col.append(p)
figs_array_row_col.append(figs_row_row_col)

grid_row_col = gridplot(figs_array_row_col)
reset_output()
show(grid_row_col)
```

[image]

Comment: You might also want to look at the recently added `marker_map` https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/plotting/file/marker_map.py